# Emacs 23 and iPython

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, emacs23

Is there anyone out there using iPython with emacs 23? The documents on the emacs wiki are a bit of a muddle and I would be interested in hearing from anyone using emacs for Python development. Do you use the download python-mode and ipython.el? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it working quite well with emacs 23. The only open issue is the focus not returning to the python buffer after sending the buffer to the iPython interpreter.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonMode#toc10

```
(setq load-path
      (append (list nil
                    "~/.emacs.d/python-mode-1.0/"
            "~/.emacs.d/pymacs/"
            "~/.emacs.d/ropemacs-0.6"
                    )
              load-path))
(setq py-shell-name "ipython")

(defadvice py-execute-buffer (around python-keep-focus activate)
  "return focus to python code buffer"
  (save-excursion ad-do-it))

(setenv "PYMACS_PYTHON" "python2.5") 
(require 'pymacs)

(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")

(provide 'python-programming)
```

Answer (score 2):

never used it myself, but I do follow the ipython mailing list, and there was a [thread](http://lists.ipython.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2008-September/thread.html) a couple months back.

maybe this will help

http://lists.ipython.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2008-September/005791.html

It's also a very responsive mailing list if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ipython with emacs cvs (which has been emacs 23 for some time now) in my python development. I, however, use it the other way around: I call emacs from the ipython promt through the $EDITOR environment variable. I tried it the other way around, but got a bit tired of all the process buffers and what not.

Emacs is great, but a command-line far more versatile.