# Ipython Emacs integration

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

Has anyone managed to get Emacs 23, python-mode.el and ipython.el working together recently?

my .emacs looks like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.0.3/")
(require 'python-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
(require 'ipython)
```

the error I'm getting on `C-c !` is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'olors' is not defined
```

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304049/emacs-23-and-ipython and this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc11

Comment: Those links are a few years old now - I read them before posting. I think the problems I'm having relate to more recent releases (judging by some of the threads on github)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ipython.el is known to be out of date. None of the core IPython developers know emacs lisp. Someone is now [working to fix it](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1015) - if you have time, please test his branch and report whether it works.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another reason someone may be getting this error:

iPython 0.12 exits with an error if given a -color arg.

What fixed it for me was replacing

```
(setq py-python-command-args '("-colors" "Linux"))
```

in my .emacs with

```
(setq py-python-command-args '("--colors=linux"))
```

That is, make sure that the args passed to iPython were valid. If not, iPython exits with error and we fall back to the regular python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error invoking IPython from Emacs23. I fixed it by replacing all instances of `-colors` with `--colors` in `ipython.el`