# Using IPython mode in Emacs 24.3

Tags: python, emacs

I am testing out the `ipython` package for Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. First, I installed both `ipython` and `python-mode` using the package manager `M-x list-packages`. For debugging, I simplified my init file `~/.emacs` to:

```
(setq debug-on-error t)
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))

(package-initialize)
(require 'ipython)
```

First question, why is `package-initialize` and `require 'ipython` needed? I thought this would work automatically out of the box after installing from the package manager?

Second question, when I run `M-x py-shell` I get the following screen shot (`t.py` is test Python script):

[image]

As seen, I get an error from IPython:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'olors' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you looked at this potential duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226493/ipython-emacs-integration

Comment: @rimero Thanks, I did not see that question. Anyway the question in the link is 3 years old, so it should be fixed by now? I tried now `(setq py-python-command-args '("--colors=linux"))` from that link, put it did not work either..

Comment: Not a direct answer, but the python.el support bundled with Emacs has been changed for 24.4 (to be released real-soon-now) so it supports IPython out of the box.  It would be great if you could try the 24.3.94 pretest to make sure that this new support indeed works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

No need for ipython.el, which causes this error.

BTW as trunk of python-mode.el is close to upcoming release, it might be worth a try.

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

bzr branch lp:python-mode